# SPF Records: Outlook shows fail, Google shows pass

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, spf

I am using Office 365 for emails, and have configured the DNS SPF record as:

`v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all`

When I send emails to Google recipients, the email headers show `Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@domain.com designates 2a01:111:f400:fe14::71b as permitted sender) client-ip=2a01:111:f400:fe14::71b;` and the message is delivered.

But for Outlook recipients, , the email headers show `Received-SPF: Fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of domain.com does not designate 192.162.217.24 as permitted sender)` and the email is marked as spam.

I don't know why the two mailbox providers are treating the record differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you resolve the relevant TXT records

```
spf.protection.outlook.com  TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:40.92.0.0/15 ip4:40.107.0.0/16 ip4:52.100.0.0/14 ip4:104.47.0.0/17 ip6:2a01:111:f400::/48 ip6:2a01:111:f403::/48 include:spfd.protection.outlook.com -all"
spfd.protection.outlook.com TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:51.4.72.0/24 ip4:51.5.72.0/24 ip4:51.5.80.0/27 ip4:20.47.149.138/32 ip4:51.4.80.0/27 ip6:2a01:4180:4051:0800::/64 ip6:2a01:4180:4050:0800::/64 ip6:2a01:4180:4051:0400::/64 ip6:2a01:4180:4050:0400::/64 -all"
```

`2a01:111:f400:fe14::71b` is authorized as sender while `192.162.217.24` is  not. If that IPv4 hosts is yours you'll need to have it included in the SPF record. If it's not yours your email configuration is flawed.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. It's a basic 365 setup though, so presumably ```192.162.217.24``` is a Microsoft server, and should be in their SPF record?

Comment: [192.162.217.24](https://www.whois.com/whois/192.162.217.24) is an electric.net server that doesn't seem to have a connection to MS. The question is why it tries to pass your mail?

Comment: Hmm... I've no idea to be honest. It's just an out-of-the-box 365 setup (from GoDaddy), so I'd have thought it would all be preset correctly.

Comment: Apparently your client uses that electric.net server as MSA. It should be an O365 server instead.

Answer (score 0):

The applicable SPF records for `spf.protection.outlook.com` (slightly modified output to easily read):

```
$ dig +short txt spf.protection.outlook.com
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all"
$ dig +short txt spf.protection.outlook.com
"v=spf1 ip4:40.92.0.0/15 \
ip4:40.107.0.0/16 \
ip4:52.100.0.0/14 \
ip4:104.47.0.0/17 \
ip6:2a01:111:f400::/48 \
ip6:2a01:111:f403::/48 \
include:spfd.protection.outlook.com -all"
$ dig +short txt spfd.protection.outlook.com
"v=spf1 ip4:51.4.72.0/24 \
ip4:51.5.72.0/24 \
ip4:51.5.80.0/27 \
ip4:20.47.149.138/32 \
ip4:51.4.80.0/27 \
ip6:2a01:4180:4051:0800::/64 \
ip6:2a01:4180:4050:0800::/64 ip6:2a01:4180:4051:0400::/64 \
ip6:2a01:4180:4050:0400::/64 -all"
```

We can see `ip6:2a01:111:f400::/48`, so the sending IP address of `2a01:111:f400:fe14::71b` passes the test.

We cannot see any `ip4` statement that would permit a sending IP address for `192.162.217.24`, so it fails the test.

The two mail providers appear to be treating the record the same.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Both emails were sent at the same time, using the same client. So why is Outlook using the IP4 address, and Google using the IP6?

Comment: They aren't doing anything other than interpreting what was sent to them. The actual question is why is a message being sent from `192.162.217.24`?

Comment: Hmm... I've no idea to be honest. It's just an out-of-the-box 365 setup (from GoDaddy). Any suggestions?